# CEF sharp displays web page but CefWebBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized always false

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have a very strange situation here with CEF Sharp x86 (67 with latest cef.redist 3.3497.1841), but originally reported with v49. It's very crazy, so I'm just looking, maybe somebody have stumbled upon anything similar. We host WPF ChromiumWebBrowser inside WinForms UserControl (via ElementHost) and it's running inside 3rd party application, with which it does not interact in any way (so it's a plugin to this host application). For about 100 or so users everything is ok, but for a single person this happens: webpage loads and displays correctly, but the ChromiumWebBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized flag is always false.

Now, by 'user' I don't mean Windows account, just a user in totally unrelated 3rd party application, logging-in against 3rd party userid/password verification - unrelated to any windows settings. So as crazy as it sounds we've tried it on multiple computers on multiple windows accounts, using different user ids for the application, and the result is still the same - for this one userid there is a problem, for others - all ok.

I wonder if anyone has had such crazy experience with CEF. I'm betting on some bug in .NET layer, as the actual browser works fine - webpage is rendered, you can browse normally. Also this has sth to do with CEF run as plugin to this exact 3rd party app - if I run a test winform app with same setup - user control -> element host -> WPF ChromiumWebBrowser, all is ok. CEF log is not much help, no errors other than in OK situation.

I'm not attaching any code or logs, I don't think it'd be helpful in this case. Just for more background the plugin has been around for almost 3 years with not a single bug reported, except this case. Just to make it clear - I need this flag to be true to be able to inject JS calls into the plugin.

Comment: Using IsBrowserInitialized  in relation to js seems strange to me, what does your code look like? There is no class called CefWebBrowser, please use the correct class names, you'll only confuse others. I've never heard of other reports.

Comment: If you haven't already then please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: Yup, meant ChromiumWebBrowser, my bad. The relation it's that when you call ExecuteScriptAsync, the flag is checked and if not true, exception is raised.

Comment: Again, the code has been in production for 3 years and it's working ok, besides this single anomaly, so rtfm is no good here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turned out to be a case of opening 2 instances of browser within single process. One browser window was initializing and working fine, second was was displaying page, but reporting 'not initialized'. It became clear only when I went to customer and actually saw the scenario, because they did not report that they opened 2nd instance. I this case, they don't need 2nd instance, so that was the fix, maybe there is an error I our code, I'll follow up this issue once we do more through analysis.